# Laravel querybuilder withCount relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-6

I'm encountering a problem with a script.
I'm working with Laravel 6.x (but there is no big difference).

So, I have a model `Order`, which has relationship with another model `Group` like this:

Model Order :

```
public function groups()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Order\Group', 'order_id')->orderBy('order_group');
}
```

Model Group :

```
public function order()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Order\Order', 'order_id');
}
```

I want all the `Order`s that have a group where the column `'is_recurrent'` inside the group is `true` AND there are at least 2 line `'is_recurrent'` `true`.

Basically this :

```
$orders = Order::withCount(['groups' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_recurrent', true);
}])
->having('groups_count', '>', 1)
->get();
```

i've try lany things, like Order::whereHas('groups', function ....).

In many cases I got :

> SQLSTATE[42803]: Grouping error: 7 ERROR:  column "ordergroups.order_group" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
> LINE 1: ... "is_recurrent" = $1 group by "order_id" order by "order_gro...
> ^ (SQL: select "orders".*, (select count(*) from "ordergroups" where "orders"."id" = "ordergroups"."order_id" and "is_recurrent
> " = 1 group by "order_id" order by "order_group" asc) as "groups_count" from "orders" having "groups_count" > 1 order by "created_at" desc)

With

```
$orders = Order::withCount(['groups' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_recurrent', true)->groupBy('order_group');
}])
->having('groups_count', '>', 1)
->get();
```

I got :

> SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "groups_count" does not exist
> LINE 1: ...roup" asc) as "groups_count" from "orders" having "groups_co...
> ^ (SQL: select "orders".*, (select count(*) from "ordergroups" where "orders"."id" = "ordergroups"."order_id" and "is_recurrent
> " = 1 group by "order_group" order by "order_group" asc) as "groups_count" from "orders" having "groups_count" > 1 order by "created_at" desc)

If someone has any clue :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `withCount` function adds a variable to your model, it isn't available within the query (at least to my knowledge).

Based on the little info of your table structure, this should give the correct result; using `whereHas` with the same query you will ensure that there is at least 1 group with `is_recurrent = true`, and using `withCount` will give you the complete count on the individual order model.

```php
$orders = Order::withCount(['groups' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_recurrent', true)->groupBy('order_group');
}])
->whereHas(['groups' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_recurrent', true)->groupBy('order_group');
}])
->get();
```